# Define spark schema for given json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I load this json to Spark dataframe without specifying schema:

```
{
 "titles": {
  "L": [
   {
    "S": "ABC"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

The result of df.printSchema() is

```
root
 |-- titles: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- L: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried and failed to translate this json schema to the code as below:

```
AS = StructType([StructField
  ("L",
    ArrayType(StructField("S", StringType(), True))
 )   
]) 

my_schema = StructType([
   StructField("titles", AS ,True)
])
```

I tried to use my_schema to read the same json and got the error:

"Failed to convert the JSON string '{"metadata":{},"name":"S","nullable":true,"type":"string"}' to a data type".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the schema you defined you are missing a level.

The content of the array `L` should be a StructType which contains the StructField `S`. You are missing this StructType.

The correct schema is

```py
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField("titles", StructType([
        StructField("L", ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField("S", StringType(), True)
            ])
        ))
    ]), True)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the dataframe using JSON, just print the schema using `print(df.schema)` as:

```py
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/content/sample_data/test.json")

print(df.schema)

[Out]:
StructType([StructField('titles', StructType([StructField('L', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('S', StringType(), True)]), True), True)]), True)])
```

The printed schema can be used "as is" to define the schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType, Row

schema_2 = StructType([StructField('titles', StructType([StructField('L', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('S', StringType(), True)]), True), True)]), True)])

data = [Row(Row([Row("ABC")]))]

spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema_2).schema

[Out]:

root
 |-- titles: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- L: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
```